# The procedure entry point _ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz could not be located in the dynamic link library sfml-graphics-2.dll

Tags: c++, sfml

Today I decided to download, install, and attempt to use SFML 2.2. I also downloaded Code::Blocks with the MinGW compiler. I set up everything and installed everything correctly (or so I thought) and tried to run a sample code to see if it would work:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiled correctly although trying to run it an error message box appears saying "The procedure entry point _ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz could not be located in the dynamic link library sfml-graphics-2.dll". I searched the web but didn't find anything related to this problem, so I came here searching for help. Thanks to further answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main reason for this issue is the import libraries for the DLL's were created for a different version of the DLL you're using.

When you built the application, you used an import library so that the linker will find the SFML functions that your application is calling.  However, the DLL itself does not contain one or more of the functions that the import library has stubs for.

When creating an application that implcitly loads a DLL entails a 3 step process:

1. Compiling the code
2. Linking the code
3. Running the code

All the compiler cares about is that the program is syntactically correct.  This worked without error.

The linker stage determines if the functions you're calling actually exist.  This is where things get tricky, since the function stubs exist in the import library, and that will satisfy the linker.  The import library tells the linker, "yes, this function is here in this DLL, so trust me".  This also worked without error for you

*(Note that this is different in a non-DLL scenario, where the linker will actually look for the function itself, not a stub).*

However, the actual functions themselves are in a different module (DLL), and the only time your application can determine their existence is when you run the program.  This is where you're stuck right now.

So the thing you should do first is make sure that the import libraries you're using when building your application match up with the DLL's that you're loading at runtime.  If you still get the error, contact where you got the DLL's and inquire how to get the proper import libraries.

In addition, there are ways to create an import library from a DLL, if for some reason you can't get the import libraries.  I don't know all the details of how to do this manually for MingW, but the information should be available online somewhere.

Comment: This does not answer the question "How to fix the problem"

Comment: @user3728501 *So the thing you should do first is make sure that the import libraries you're using when building your application match up with the DLL's that you're loading at runtime. If you still get the error, contact where you got the DLL's and inquire how to get the proper import libraries.*

Comment: That doesn't mean anything to me - it does not answer the question

Comment: I am not a windows programmer

Comment: @user3728501 If you are not a Windows programmer, then of course it won't make sense to you.  The question implies Windows due to the usage of DLL's.

Comment: Can you explain it to a non-windows programmer so he can fix the problem on his windows pc?

Comment: The explanation given is enough.  If you are not familiar with what a Dynamic Link Library is, there are vast resources as to define what they are.  If you are writing a program that will use a DLL, then any functions in your program that will call a DLL exported function must be placed within a library at link time (or use LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress).  This is basic stuff, and trying to explain that in a comment box is something that can't be done.

Comment: Yes, I understand what a dll is. Some things which I didn't understand: "The linker stage determines if the functions you're calling actually exist. This is where things get tricky, since the function stubs exist in the import library, and that will satisfy the linker. The import library tells the linker, "yes, this function is here in this DLL, so trust me". This also worked without error for you " What is this import library?

Comment: "So the thing you should do first is make sure that the import libraries you're using when building your application match up with the DLL's that you're loading at runtime. If you still get the error, contact where you got the DLL's and inquire how to get the proper import libraries." - how exactly do I do this?

Comment: "In addition, there are ways to create an import library from a DLL, if for some reason you can't get the import libraries. I don't know all the details of how to do this manually for MingW, but the information should be available online somewhere." - This isn't helpful at all

Comment: By the way I think you mean "function prototype" not "stub"? If not then I have misunderstood what you mean by a "stub"

Comment: The import library is what the author is supposed to give you as part of the build package.  If he / she did not give it to you, then go to the author and ask for it.  If they can't do that, then you need to build it yourself, or if not that, use LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress to call your function(s).  Seriously,  all of this information can be gotten here and on-line as to what these things I'm explaining are.  You don't have access to google?

Comment: And no, I mean "function stub".  The import library contains the information to satisfy the *linker*.  The prototypes are not used by the linker, but by the *compiler*.  Did you downvote this?  If you did, I don't see any justification for it, as it answered the question thoroughly, enough for the OP to accept it and move on.  You're asking basic questions that are outside the scope of what was originally discussed.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as the OP and yet I have no idea what is even the first step of "what I should actually __*do*__ to being resolving the problem" - that sounds like a problem to me. I can't comment on the down-voting. Perhaps someone else doesn't find your answer helpful?

Comment: `So the thing you should do first is make sure that the import libraries you're using when building your application match up with the DLL's that you're loading at runtime.`  Did you do this?  This is a basic fundamental of creating a program that will interface to a third-party DLL.  Rather than drawing this out any longer, why not get familiar with the tools that you are required to have knowledge of?  I can't help you, as again, there are **tons** of resources explaining the build process wrt interfacing with DLL functions.

Comment: This is exactly why your answer is inadequate. I asked you already. _How do I do that?_

Comment: The simplest thing to do is wipe any traces of SFML from your machine, import libraries, DLL's, and start from the beginning with the entire package given to you by the author (don't try and cobble things together yourself -- get the full, original package).  You are either using an out of date import library, loading an incompatible DLL, or the runtime is not correct.   It can be multiple things, but the main reason for such error is what I have been stating.   Can it be the only reason, no.  But is the most likely.

Comment: "and start from the beginning with the entire package given to you by the author" -> do you mean compile SFML from source here?

Comment: If the instructions are to compile the entire source, then yes.  In the compilation step (more precisely, the "post build" step after compilation), a set of .lib files should be created.  Those versions should be the correct versions that you would then apply to your app's project settings (I am assuming that the build included building the import libs)

Comment: Okay, but what about the dll's? Are these likely to come with SFML? Do I need to build them myself?

Comment: Building the SFML should also build the DLL's necessary.  So you should see both DLL's and LIB files being built.

Comment: Thank you this begins to answer my question

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct solution, but a workaround would be to try static linking. It looks like SFML's tutorial talks about this, and it involves adding `SFML_STATIC` to your `#defines` section. Your exe's will be larger, but they'll also be more independent.

I had the same problem and static linking worked, although I was using mingw-w64 i686 alongside cmake. You would download SFML's source code, and then in the cmake settings, you would:

- Choose the source and build folders
- Click 'Configure' and for the generator, select "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles"
- turn off `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`
- turn on `SFML_BUILD_EXAMPLES` and `SFML_USE_STATIC_STD_LIBS`
- change `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to Debug (optional, for helpful error messages)
- click 'Configure', then 'Generate'

There will be a .cbp file in the build folder. Also, the examples might tell you either the 'resources' folder or openal32.dll are missing, so you just need to add those to the examples in your build folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially stating that your compiler is different from the one that SFML used.

You can solve this by downloading the specific version for each. For CodeBlocks, you just download(mingw16.01):
http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26

For SFML, you just download GCC 4.9.2 TDM (SJLJ):
https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.4.2/