# The procedure entry point _ZDt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\[Location of vector.exe]

Tags: c++, vector, mingw

This question IS different than the others. I am a beginner C++ programmer and I was recently learning vector arrays. Here is my code, which is straight from my book:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    vector <int> vec(3,100) ;

    cout << "Vector size: " << vec.size() << endl ;
    cout << "Is empty?: " << vec.empty() << endl ;
    cout << "First element: " << vec.at(0) << endl ;

    vec.pop_back() ; // Remove final element.
    cout << "Vector size: " << vec.size() << endl ;
    cout << "Final element: " << vec.back() << endl;

    vec.clear() ; // Remove all elements.
    cout << "Vector size: " << vec.size() << endl;

    vec.push_back( 200 ) ; // Add an element.
    cout << "Vector size: " << vec.size() << endl ;
    cout << "First element: " << vec.front() << endl ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

I keep getting the error message

> The procedure entry point `_ZDt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz` could not be located in the dynamic link library `c:\[Location of vector.exe]`

Please keep in mind that I am a beginner and I just want to know how to fix this. I am using the MinGW compiler. Thanks!

Comment: Possible dll confilct.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Okay. Is there any dll files I need to replace or something? I thought it did not have anything to do with the code because all compiled well. How can I run the file?

Comment: Your error message confuses me. Normally this should be a .dll not an .exe. Can you take a screen shot of the exact error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221184/the-procedure-entry-point-zst24-throw-out-of-range-fmtpkcz-could-not-be-locate

Comment: Do you have more than 1 version of mingw installed on your hard drive?

Comment: @drescherjm I don't think so.

Comment: What command are you compiling with `gcc` or `g++`?

Comment: @RichardCritten The command is g++.